# Can you use events in React components?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, reactjs

I'm trying to build a modal, and I have this code: https://jsfiddle.net/j2r15hxg/4/

Currently, I'm using an onClick event on my ModalBackdrop component to try hiding the modal and backdrop together:

```
<ModalBackdrop onClick={this.closeModal} isOpen={this.state.isOpen}>
```

However this doesn't work. Why is that, and how can I get around it? My guess would be because you can't use events on React components, but I couldn't find anything in the docs saying you can/can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your JS Fiddle fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/j2r15hxg/5/

Basically, in the backdrop you were trying to call the handler "this.closeModal" which is not defined in your `Backdrop` component but in the parent component (`modalSignInButton`). In general, you provide a callback as a prop of your child components and they use it when they need to notify its parent.

Comment: Thanks! I've noticed that also goes away when you click inside the modal; for anyone who's interested in final thing where I fix that they can view it here: https://jsfiddle.net/45gLw77f/1/